# Which should be the standard implementation of static jagged arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

If i want this, somehow, continuously in memory:

```
arrs = {{a,b}, {a,b,c}, ...}
```

(I know the size of each array at compile time)

Which is the, generally, optimal implementation.
I have seen a similar question, about an specific design (they also point other solutions). However, I immediately thought of another method; so, i wonder, since there are multiple ways of representing the same thing, which should I usually prefer, is there something close to a standard?

Here are some options I know: (being index_t uint8/16/32_t)

(1) Array of <pointer to array, size of array>

```
T arr1[] = {...}
T arr2[] = {...}
<T*, index_t> arrs[] = {{arr1, arr1_sz}, {arr2, arr2_sz}}
```

(1.5) If you use the heap, you could do instead std::vector of std::vector of T

(2) Array of pointers to arrays with a reserved "end element"

```
T arr1[] = {..., $}
T arr2[] = {..., $}
T* arrs[] = {arr1, arr2}
```

(3) Array with all the other array elements stored continuously and an array of indices.

```
T arrs[] = {..., ...}
const index_t idx[] = {0, arr1_sz, arr1_sz + arr2_sz}
```

And here are some facts i have identified about each option:

(1) Will need 4 bytes (pointer) + 1/2/4 bytes (index_t), per each array.

(2) Will need 4 bytes (pointer) + sizeof(T) bytes (end element), per each array.

(3) Will need 1/2/4 bytes (index_t), per each array (+1, for the 0)

Despite the third option seems, to me, more memory friendly, i haven't seen it in this forum yet (maybe i didn't search enough). So, which, not only from this 3, but from all the known designs, should I use and why.

By "what should i, generally, use", i mean which option  is the nearest to becoming a standard. Note that the answer could be none, if you prove there are great performance differences between two common cases.

Comment: you need to pick C or C++, they are two different languages and the answers will vary a lot.

Comment: In C++ you just use `std::vector` and stop worrying about it. In C you have to do it yourself and there's a lot of different ways that depend entirely on your use case, which you haven't described. Weighing the cost in terms of bytes is completely missing the point. Bytes are cheap.

Comment: Ok, i changed it to C++. Remember i want it in the stack. "const vector" don't use the heap?

Comment: Note `size_t` is a lot larger than any array you're likely to have. It's for the *largest possible array* on hardware that doesn't even exist yet, like you can have a 12EB array on some machine with that much memory.

Comment: A) What is this and where is it used? B) To the nearest order of magnitude, how much data are we talking about?

Comment: Oh sorry, i used size_t, not as the std::size_t, but as a type to be defined depending on the size. I would add that description, thanks for the report.

Comment: Making your own type called `size_t` is pretty dirty. Why not `index_t` or something less misleading? Explaining more about the use case would help considerably in determining the best course of action here.

Comment: Still, i dont get your std::vector suggestion. If i want to maximize performance and i know the size of all the arrays, why should i use the heap, generally as u suggest, instead of the stack?

Comment: Are the row arrays pretty small? and do you know the size at compile time?

Comment: The rows could be small or big and you know the size at compile time.

Comment: If you put everything on the stack and they are big there's a good chance of a stack overflow. The stack really isn't made for very large data.  How big whereabouts?

Comment: Sure, i mean, not big enough to make that happen. I am asking: if you want this static container, is there something close to an standard? Asuming you use it correctly: you evaluate the problem and you decide its better to use the stack then the heap (taking in consideration the stack properties).

Comment: Well if you are going to make that kind of decision, at run time you don't know at compile time.  However you can use alloca and write a quick and dirty class to do what you need. But alloca is technically not in the standard. However a lot of compilers support it so depending on what you are doing it may be an option.

Comment: Asuming you know exactly the amount of elements, you should make that decision while you write the code. Let say, you know that, for the first array you need X elements, for the second Y, for the third... and so on, then you ask your self, with this type of data should i use the stack or the heap?, and your answer is the stack...then thats the scenario. Is there a standard static jagged array? is one of the 3 solution i showed, generally, prefered? is there another?

Comment: I'm not sure you will find something that will automatically do that for you at compile time.  Likely you could write it with templates without too much trouble if you know what you want. std::array should put things on the stack if you know for sure you always want stuff there. Also if this function is recursive, keep that in mind because recursive functions tend to use a lot of stack space.

Comment: You generally want to avoid using the stack for stuff that sticks around like this, which is why `std::vector` uses the heap, it keeps the stack usage more minimal. If these are `const` and have a static lifetime then that they might use the heap is more of an academic concern than anything. It's important to note that "stack" does not equal "faster", all memory is effectively same speed. You could use `std::array`, which might help keep things contiguous.

Comment: I think we are going in circles. IF you decide to use a jagged array and you decide to use the stack for it. Is there a commonly prefered design? Thats my question. The answer could be: (1) a class with metaprogramming (as answered recently), (2) a general code structure (as one of the 3 example i gave) and (3) "none, because even after deciding the jagged arr and the stack, there is usually a lot more decisions that alter the implementation" (with an example)

Comment: While that is some clever code, I'm not sure what advantages, if any, that approach buys you over `const X = std::vector<std::vector<T>>`. Remember, you want to *avoid using the stack* for data that isn't ephemeral. Stack space is quite limited and needs to be conserved. It's also worth noting that a top-level `const` doesn't use the stack at all, it's a static data structure.

Comment: I get your point. Maybe giving to much attetion to the stack case, was wrong from me. The main objective was a continuous jagged array. I though that by limiting the workspace to the stack i would get the same answer. However, as you say, seems to hypothetical. Okay, now imagine, you have data that isn't ephemeral and you use the heap. JaggedArray* vs const vector<vector<>>. Note that the vec of vec is basically the (1) example i gave, which consumes more memory than the JaggedArray from the answer. I will update the main goal, thanks so much for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You clarified in the comments that you know the sizes at compile time and you are interested in non-dynamic allocation. So

You can create a jagged array template type with all the matrix flattened and all the size information encoded in the type (no need to extra pointer/index storage). Implementing it is not so trivial though. Actually once you get over the 2D-1D index transformation it is smooth sail from there on. Here is a bare bone [implementation](https://godbolt.org/z/To8obY):

```
template <class T, std::size_t... Sizes>
struct JaggedArray
{
    static constexpr std::size_t FlatSize = (... + Sizes);

    std::array<T, FlatSize> flatten;

    template <size_t RowIdx>
    static constexpr size_t row_size()
    {
        return std::array{Sizes...}[RowIdx];
    }

    template <std::size_t... SizeIdx>
    static constexpr std::size_t flat_idx(std::size_t row_idx, std::size_t column_idx,
                                          std::index_sequence<SizeIdx...>)
    {
        // check row out of range
        if (row_idx >= sizeof...(Sizes))
            throw std::out_of_range{"row index out of range"};

        // check column out of range
        if (column_idx >= (... + (SizeIdx == row_idx ? row_size<SizeIdx>() : 0)))
            throw std::out_of_range{"column index out of range"};
        
        // sum all the row sizes for rows before row_idx
        // and add the column index
        return (... + (SizeIdx < row_idx ? row_size<SizeIdx>() : 0)) + column_idx;
    }

    static constexpr std::size_t flat_idx(std::size_t row_idx, std::size_t column_idx)
    {
        return flat_idx(row_idx, column_idx,
                        std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(Sizes)>{});
    }

    constexpr const T& at(std::size_t row_idx, std::size_t column_idx) const
    {
        return flatten[flat_idx(row_idx, column_idx)];
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
constexpr JaggedArray<int, 3, 2, 5, 1, 3> a{
    0, 1, 2,
    10, 11,
    20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
    30,
    40, 41, 42
};

static_assert(3 + 2 + 5 + 1 + 3 == 14);
static_assert(sizeof(a) == 14 * sizeof(int));
static_assert(a.FlatSize == 14);

static_assert(a.at(0, 0) == 0);
static_assert(a.at(0, 1) == 1);
static_assert(a.at(0, 2) == 2);

static_assert(a.at(1, 0) == 10);
static_assert(a.at(1, 1) == 11);

static_assert(a.at(2, 0) == 20);
static_assert(a.at(2, 1) == 21);
static_assert(a.at(2, 2) == 22);
static_assert(a.at(2, 3) == 23);
static_assert(a.at(2, 4) == 24);

static_assert(a.at(3, 0) == 30);

static_assert(a.at(4, 0) == 40);
static_assert(a.at(4, 1) == 41);
static_assert(a.at(4, 2) == 42);

// a.at(1, 2); // out_of_range (compile time if constant eval or runtime)
```

Comment: Love it. Thank you so much for this. Is there any drawback with this implementation? Seems unbeatable to me, since you transform all the coordinates args during compile time.

Comment: I don't see any obvious drawbacks. Maybe the difficulty of the implementation, but after you unit test it properly it shouldn't be a problem

Comment: In "check column out of range", could you do instead row_size<array{SizeIdx...}[row_idx]>() ? Is there any benefit?

Comment: @nutax I've put a godbolt link you can play in and test for yourself. And no, you can't do that because `row_idx` is not a constant expression. But you can do `std::array{Sizes...}[std::array{SizeIdx...}[row_idx]]`. Which one you use is mostly a matter of preferences.

Comment: Thanks! (I wasn't able to test it at the moment and i was so curious :P)